# Get url content with ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, url, quotes

I am trying to get content of a url page with ajax but I have problem with quotes

The content of the page is :

```
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>[u'Canchim cattle', u'Cancer hospital', u'Cancer antigen 50','Cancer antigen 125'] </body>
```

I have tried with jquery :

```
 $.ajax({ url: url, 
          dataType: "jsonp", 
          success: function(data) 
          { 
             alert(data); 
          } 
       });
```

I have also tried in dataType "json" ,"text" "application/json charset=utf-8", "html", "text/html". 
With "jsonp" I get the error:

```
Syntax error illegal character [u &\#39;Can ...
```

and in the other formats nothing is happening only a 200 OK is showing in firebug console.

I have also changed the text of the page in ['Canchim cattle','Cancer hospital'] like a simple list but I still had problems with quotes. I removed them and then ajax could not parse spaces between words.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? I'm having no problems here.

Comment: Is there a way for you to test with an updated jQuery?

Comment: Ok I will try. Do you have any version to suggest? Also for jquery autocomplete?